# How to change values based on if another column contains specific text?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset where I need to change values for any device that does not contain the text "INV" to 0.

```
    
Device     Value
RGM        4279
INV A1     727
INV A2     3731
POA        73974
```

I figured something like this would work, but it doesn't.

```
if (grepl(!"INV", df$Device, fixed = TRUE) {
  df$Value <- 0
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Base Solution

To modify things the way you originally intended, simply subscript `df$Value` to target the nonmatches, and overwrite them with `<- 0`:

```
df$Value[!grepl("INV", df$Device, fixed = TRUE)] <- 0
```

## Tidy Alternative

Alternatively, if you want to work within [**`tidyverse`**](https://www.tidyverse.org/) convention, this should do the trick with [**`dplyr`**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  # Mutate the column as a whole.
  mutate(
    Value = if_else(
      # Determine which values in the column match the regex.
      grepl("INV", Value, fixed = TRUE),
      # Overwrite any nonmatches with 0; otherwise keep the original value.
      Value, 0
    )
  )
```